# i am getting reference error in withTracker mongo find function?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am getting error  **AllCustomers.js:54 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'userKisan' before initialization** but I have imported the related file and dont know why it is show this error the github code is [this link](https://github.com/mgonekar/Meteor-Test-App/blob/master/imports/ui/AllCustomers.js)

```
import {userKisan}   from '../api/userKisan';

  export default withTracker( ( props ) => {
    const filesHandle = Meteor.subscribe('userKisan');
    const docsReadyYet = filesHandle.ready();
    const userKisan = userKisan.find({}).fetch(); // error

    return {
      docsReadyYet,
      userKisan,
    };
  })(AllCustomers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {userKisandb}   from '../api/userKisan';

export default withTracker( ( props ) => {
    const filesHandle = Meteor.subscribe('userKisan');
    const docsReadyYet = filesHandle.ready();
    const userKisan = userKisandb.find({}).fetch(); 

    return {
      docsReadyYet,
      userKisan,
    };
  })(AllCustomers);
```

Comment: Change userKisan to userKisandb. always check the variable name you will export if the same to avoid error.